# Merge six files based on column 1

Tags: r, perl

I have 6 csv files that I want to merge based on the string identity in Column 1. I want to preserve the Count-number in column 2 for each files. Se example below:

file1:

```
TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGAC 88902
TAGCACCATTTGAAATCAGTGTT 62017
TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGA  25339
GCATGGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTC    18477
TAGCACCATCTGAAATCGGTTA  12522
CACGGTCCCCCGCGAGGGGGGCCCGGG 11814
TAAAGTGCTGACAGTGCAGAT   10870
GCGCCCTTAGCTCAGTTGGATAGAGCAA    10353
TGTGCAAATCTATGCAAAACTGA 8689
```

file2:

```
TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGAC 290460
TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGA  85960
GCATGGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTC    33273
TAGCACCATTTGAAATCAGTGTT 25284
TAGCACCATCTGAAATCGGTTA  21199
AGTTGGTTAGAGCAACCGG 18608
AGCAGCATTGTACAGGGCTATGA 18449
TGTGCAAATCCATGCAAAACTGA 17968
TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGACA    15530
CACGGTCCCCCGCGAGGGGGGCCCGGG 13258
TGTGCAAATCTATGCAAAACTGA 12847
CCTAAGGCAGGACTGATGACTGGGGTG 12725
GCCGCCGGTGAAATACCACTACTC    11971
TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTT  10398
```

file3:

```
TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGAC 181279
TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGA  78661
AGTTGGTTAGAGCAACCGG 24225
CACGGTCCCCCGCGAGGGGGGCCCGGG 22252
AAAAGCTGGGTTGAGAGGGCGA  21334
TGTGCAAATCCATGCAAAACTGA 18541
CGGCGGGTGTTGACGCGATG    17818
TAGCACCATCTGAAATCGGTTA  15642
CCTAAGGCAGGACTGATGACTGGGGTG 14003
TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGACA    12549
TAGCACCATTTGAAATCAGTGTT 12515
AGCAGCATTGTACAGGGCTATGA 12205
```

Output:

```
ID                        file1         file2             file3
TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGAC   88902         290460            181279
....
....
```

Comment: Can you share with us your attempts thus far?

Answer (score 5):

Keep all the `data.frames` in a `list` and use `Reduce/merge`.  Assuming that the name of the `first` column is `ID` across all datasets and second column name is `file1`, `file2` etc..

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='ID'), list(df1, df2, df3))
#                           ID file1  file2  file3
#1 CACGGTCCCCCGCGAGGGGGGCCCGGG 11814  13258  22252
#2      TAGCACCATCTGAAATCGGTTA 12522  21199  15642
#3     TAGCACCATTTGAAATCAGTGTT 62017  25284  12515
#4      TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGA 25339  85960  78661
#5     TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGAC 88902 290460 181279
```

If there are no `headers`, you could read it using `read.table/read.csv` with `header=FALSE`.  Then, the column names would be `V1`, `V2` for all the datasets.  I would also read it in a list using `lapply`.  Assuming that you already read it individually,

```
 setNames(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='V1'),
          list(df1, df2, df3)),c('ID', paste0('file',1:3)) )
```

If you want to read all the files in a `list` from the `working directory`

```
 files <- list.files(pattern='^file\\d+.csv')
 lst <- lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x,header=FALSE))
 setNames(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='V1'),
          lst),c('ID', paste0('file',seq_along(files))) )
```

Comment: I think the names of the data sets are `file1`, `file2`, etc. Rather these are the column names

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Thanks, yes it looks like that.  So, perhaps, the column names should `V1`, `V2` etc autogenerated.